# jQuery Breaks in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

jQuery Breaks in MVC4

I have jQuery, jQuery Mobile and jQuery-UI included in my MVC4 project. I am having a problem where the jQuery-UI script only loads if the page is refreshed, otherwise the jQuery-UI will not load initially.

I have tried moving the include script to the bottom of the page instead of including it in the top. This seems to work 80% of the time with one side effect. When I post some data to the server, I would get two posts instead of one.. ugh! I seem to be stuck and I can find anything on Google that will help alleviate my problem. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is some added code

Here is my _layout.cshtlm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>              

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multi-accordion-1.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myjQuery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>

        <header>
        <script>
        </script>
            <div class="content-wrapper wrappingBorder bottomRound shadow" style="background-color:White;margin:0 auto 30px auto;">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="title">NTI Project Management</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                  @*<section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>*@
                        <nav>
                            <ul id="menu">
                                <li >@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "Project")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Index", "Logout")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        @*Start of main content*@
        <div id="body">
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix allRound shadow">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p style="font-size: 14px">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - 3M</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        </div>   

    </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: The issue doesn't seems to related to MVC. Use firebug to see if scripts loaded successfully

Comment: This may happen because there is a conflict between JQM and JQ-UI, JQM is create over JQ-UI, so if you notice both JQM.css and JQ-UI.css have several classes with same name. May be your problem is because of this conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your loading JQUI etc before your loading in JQ lib

Try moving it in this order in the head of your _layout/master page:

- JQ
- JQUI
- Others

Alternaitvely, make sure you only call each library once, and your using the latest versions of both libraries:
 - JQ:   1.7.1
 - JQUI: 1.8.21

Furthermore, double check that the libraries are actually 'there'. Go into View Source > Head > Click on each script's URL to see if you are specifying the wrong location in MVC. 
(Sometimes happens when using Content.URL/URL.Action incorrectly)

It may load the second time you have refreshed due to browser caching

As far as the double post goes, if it still persists after checking the above, showing some code would also help us assist you

Comment: I added some code and tried what you said. No avail though.  @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: The problem was with jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile is breaking jQuery UI. Do you know how to circumvent this? @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: @446f6f20446f6f Have you made sure you're using the latest version? If you use Chrome or Firebug you should be able to see what the error is. Usually it comes down to load order. Does your code work if you remove the bundles?

Comment: My code works if I remove the bundles and add the references manually. Once I add a reference to jQuery Mobile, jQuery UI breaks. I also just updated to the newest version of jQuery Mobile. @JustAnotherDeveloper

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the bundling first to see if there is a load order issue going on. It looks like you're bundling the scripts/js folder and loading that before jquery and jquery.ui, could this be the issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate more?  @Chris Conway

Comment: Remove the line of code where you are using the bundling (right before you load jQuery from jquery.com. Then you'll have to add some script references manually for anything that exists in the scripts/js folder that were being bundled for you. Perhaps something in there is relying on jQuery (which hasn't been loaded yet).

Comment: Thank you! I removed that bundle and the jQuery UI loaded correctly. I'm going to add the scripts back manually to find out which one is the culprit. @Chris Conway